# Rsync creating \#015 directory

Tags: sync, rsync, symbolic-link

I have a virtual ubuntu server running on my windows server. This server has 2 external hdd's attached, which are mounted in ubuntu.

Now I try to run rsync to sync a directory on my desktop and my windows server.

I do this as follows:

```
rsync -av --update christophe@begijnhof.no-ip.org:/home/seagate/Syncfolder/Pictures/ /syncs/pictures
```

The `/syncs/pictures` is a symlink to `/cygdrive/c/../pictures`. All these symlinks work correctly, and the remote directory exists too.

Now when I run that rsync command above it does this:

```
created directory /syncs/pictures\#015
```

This actually creates a directory named "pictures" in my /syncs/ folder. So not in the symlink. Next to the symlink:

```
$ ls
pictures pictures?
```

When I add a trailing slash to the destination:

```
rsync -av --update christophe@begijnhof.no-ip.org:/home/seagate/Syncfolder/Pictures/ /syncs/pictures/
```

It creates a directory named "#015" (the weird dot) inside my actual Pictures folder on my tower!

I think it has something to do with encoding?

I wrote all the bash scripts in notepad++ with encoding to ANSI.

Comment: I solved this by running dos2unix in Windows on all the script files. You can also do this in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by running [dos2unix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/) in Windows on all the script files. You can also do this in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem here - at least in my case - was that the file in question had the Windows convention of a CR+LF charater at the end of the script file, as opposed to the *nix convention of simply using LF only.  To fix this, you need to change the script file itself so that it following *nix conventions.  The answer above suggests a couple of good ways to do that.  Some editors (e.g. Notepad++) have similar functionality built-in.